# Foreach Array not being created correctly

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I am generating an array using a foreach like so...

```
<?php
$docs = array();
$media = get_attached_media('image');
foreach($media as $medias) {
    $docs[] = $medias->guid;
}
$images = serialize(array('docs' => $docs));
print_r($images);
?>
```

The output I am getting is...

```
a:1:{s:4:docs";a:3:{i:0;s:62:"http://www.example.com/image1.jpg";i:1;s:62:"http://www.example.com/image2.jpg";i:2;s:62:"http://www.example.com/image3.jpg";}}"
```

But what I need is...

```
a:1:{s:4:"docs";a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:35:"http://wwww.example.com/image1.jpg";}i:1;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:35:"http://wwww.example.com/image2.jpg";}i:2;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:35:"http://wwww.example.com/image3.jpg";}i:3;a:1:{s:15:"property_imgurl";s:35:"http://wwww.example.com/image4.jpg";}}}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have more items in `$media` array than you want

Comment: Its not the number of items in the array that i'm having a problem with.   Its the property_imgurl part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your expecting `$medias->guid` to be an array, but it's a string. I believe your going to need to provide an array value when pushing into your array. This should work for you:

```
$docs = array();
$media = get_attached_media('image');
foreach($media as $medias) {
    $docs[] = array("property_imgurl" => $medias->guid);
}

$images = serialize(array('docs' => $docs));
print_r($images);
```